# How to install OS from .iso without tumb/dvd drive

Tags: windows-8, iso-image, windows-10-upgrade

I want to install windows 10( I am using windows 8 currently). First I tried to use MediaCreation tool to directly install it into my PC. But it failed repeatedly so I decided to install it using .iso file. I know how to boot into boot screen but it is to time consuming. So I want to install .iso file directly from PC...
I have no Idea how to do this?
Any kind of help is appreciable.
Thank you!

Comment: Installing an OS is a serious job. We don't generally consider "booting into the boot screen" to be "time consuming" considering how serious that job is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. At first you have to extract the files from the `iso` in your hard disc. Remember, you must not extract the files in a drive where you are going to install Windows (say C: drive). To extract the `iso` you will find so many tools in the internet if you google for it. I recommend to use `WinRar` which is easy to use.

After extraction, the next steps are simple. Go to that folder where the files from `iso` are extracted and you will find a file named `setup.exe`. Double click on that and the installation will start.

**N.B.:** If you install windows in this way without booting from BIOS, you will not be able to choose advanced options of drive formatting during installation.

Comment: what is drive formatting

Comment: During installation by booting from bios, in a step you are given a option to choose the partition where to install windows and from there you can delete any partition, format partition or create new partition. But if you install directly without booting, then you can only choose existing partition to install windows but can't delete or format those.

Comment: "*what is drive formatting*" would ring alarm bells for me & prompt me to change the answer from [what is a perfectly good one] above to "buy a USB drive, they're really cheap."

Comment: Not far enough @Tetsujin. The alarm bells in my head are telling me to suggest they take their computer to the local people who know better and pay them to do the deed.